# Why || {} in parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {}

Tags: javascript

What is this javascript syntax?
   parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};

especially this part    || {}

It is taken from this javascript code (at http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/)

```
// Creates a namespace
function namespace(namespaceString) {
    var parts = namespaceString.split('.'),
        parent = window,
        currentPart = '';

    var length = parts.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            currentPart = parts[i];
            parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};
            parent = parent[currentPart];
         }

     return parent;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator in javascript works a little differently than many other languages. In javascript, it evaluates to the first 'truthy' value, allowing a "fallthrough" sort of behavior.

Example:

```
var a = false;
var b = "asdf";
alert(a || b); //alert box with "asdf" since a was false

var c = true;
var d = "asdf";
var e = false;
alert(c || d || d); //alert box with true. d and e were never evaluated, so "asdf" isn't returned. This is called "short-circuiting" operation.
```

The `&&` operator works similarly in that it evaluates to the first 'falsey' value or the last 'truthy' value if everything is true:

```
var a = true;
var b = "asdf";
alert(a && b); //alert box with "asdf"
alert(b && a): //alert box with true

var c = 6;
var d = 0;
alert(c && d); //alert box with 0
alert(d && c); //alert box with 0
```

Comment: i could not mark all 4 answers as "Answer".  It would be the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The [definition of the `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is:

> `expr1 || expr2` Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

If `parent[currentPart]` does not exist, then the expression evaluates to an empty object (`{}`) and thus `parent[currentPart]` is initialized to that empty object. If it does exist, then it is left unchanged (that is, it is assigned to itself). The effect is to guarantee that `parent[currentPart]` always has a (non-[falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)) value.

Answer (score 1):

In JS, logical operators (e.g. `&&`, `||`) *return* a value, which, when part of an expression, can be used in an assignment.

Thus in the code below:

```
var a = false
  , b = 'hello'
  , c = (function() { return a || b })()
```

`c` is assigned the string `'hello'`, because `||` returns `'hello'` to the `return` statement, which, in turn, returns it from the function and makes the assignment to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `a = b || c`, `a` will be set to `b` if `b` evaluates to `true`; otherwise, `a` will be set to `c`. This is often used because `null` and `undefined` both evaluate to `false`, so it's shorter than saying something like `if (b == null) {a = c} else {a = b}`.